"localhost refused to connect." Error When Accessing Elasticsearch on Localhost After Running elasticsearch.bat
I'm trying to run Elasticsearch on my local machine by executing elasticsearch.bat, but I'm encountering a "Connection refused" error when I try to access it via http://localhost:9200.
Here are the steps I've taken:
1.I downloaded Elasticsearch and navigated to the bin directory.
2.I executed the command elasticsearch.bat to start the server.
3.After a few moments, I tried to access Elasticsearch using a web browser, but I received a "localhost refused to connect." error.
Ensured that Elasticsearch started without errors (no critical errors in the console).
Verified that the default port (9200) is not being used by any other application.
Checked firewall settings to ensure they are not blocking the connection.
Despite these efforts, I am still unable to connect.
Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

as I already mentioned (on the Staging ground), you need to add https:// before the url!
Instead of http://localhost:9200, you must use https://localhost:9200.
Since elastic generated a self-signed certificate, your browser will warn you, but you can continue in this case.
Regarding curl:
If you try curl without adding https, you will get the error you mentioned:
$ curl localhost:9200
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

$ curl -k https://localhost:9200
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception" ...

(the -k option bypasses the self-signed certificate - do not use this on public websites on the internet, only in this case for localhost, please!)
So, just try https://localhost:9200 in your browser, bypass the certificate warnings (I found some hints here, but it depends on your browser, the OS and the version of your browser) and then login using the username elastic and the password displayed on your terminal.
